# Where to store custom configuration files

Tags: c#, windows-7, file-io

I currently store a serialized XML file in the application directory that contains all changes specific to the program operation (not typical system or user configuration). Weeks ago, we started running into problems where it would not save correctly (read [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153386/alternative-to-xml-serialization-for-configuration) about this).

Long story short, we finally discovered that Windows 7 (and sometimes Vista) has an issue with writing into the application directory (specifically anything under Program Files). Now, if this were a normal configuration file I would simply store it under the user's APPDATA folder, but it is not normal. We run this on our own instrumentation, and misconfigurations are 99% of the reason customers have issues running our software. So we need this file to be accessible such that they can easily find it and email it to us. Appdata is hard enough for experienced users to find, much less very non-technological people.

We've also tried running it as Administrator, and making folder permissions wide open (we have control over every computer it runs on; it will never run on some random person's machine). But, these sometimes work, and sometimes do not.

The worst part is that when I write the file back out, it doesn't even throw an error; it simply writes it to some temporary directory that expires at some unknown point in time. Weeks later, our user will have an issue, and the configuration file is all messed up.

So, my question is where should I be storing this file, if not in Program Files? Should I just put it in APPDATA anyway, and make a small utility that emails it to us automatically in case of a problem? Or can I leave it in Program Files, but change some specific permission or registry key to allow it to operate normally?

Comment: AppData is the place for it. See also my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219255/why-do-files-get-placed-c-users-usernameappdata-local-virtualstore-program-fil/3219276#3219276

Comment: I know it's the correct place, but how should I then get technologically-illiterate users to send us the file in case of an issue?

Comment: @0xA3 Ideally I could fix all the bugs in both our software as well as the 9-12 hardware vendors and drivers we use in our software, but then I wouldn't be asking this question. ;) When the users send that configuration file, I am them able to handle every off case that causes a problem, but many things we simply can't foresee. For example, setting one device's parameter to 256 caused an overflow, even though the driver and the pinvokes showed it should go up to 65k. The kicker is that 257 worked fine.

Comment: The reason your writes don't throw an error is because you don't have a manifest. The virtual store is actually easy to find (once you know the trick) and doesn't expire. Bring up a Windows Explorer to the folder where you think it should be (eg C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader to pick a path on my machine) and click Compatibility Files in the toolbar below the address. Presto - you've found the virtual store.

That said, give your app a manifest and choose an appropriate per-user location to write this file. I just like to dispell the virtual store mystery when I can.

Comment: Thank you Kate! That is incredibly helpful information. I'd glossed over that "Compatibility Files" button probably hundreds of times. That could have saved us quite a few phone calls. Appreciate the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the user needs to edit the file directly. If not, you should put them in %APPDATA%, which you can access via:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Otherwise, you might put it in My Documents:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Either way, putting it in Program Files is not a good idea. As you discovered, there are permission issues, even if running as Administrator.

Comment: The user will indeed need to occasionally edit it directly. I did not even think of putting it into My Documents... Normally this would be an absurd idea, but since these computers are controlled by us, this will be a perfectly acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

For those users, you could build a button in that would open this directory. You could put it in an inconspicuous place that you could later direct them to.

For users that have an email client on their box, you could have a button that would create a new email with subject and automatically attach the file to the email.